# xfce shortcut won't launch Firefox w/ Intel Flash support, CLI command will

Tags: firefox, flash, xfce

One can start Firefox with flash support by Intel graphics cards/chips from the terminal via

```
VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

However I'd like to do that from a shortcut in my XFCE panel (little screenshot of panel). So I simply thought of editing the command

[image]

but that doesn't work. How can I achieve that?

(If others are interested in this, you could check out [this post on webup8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/adobe-flash-player-hardware.html).)

[image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the call to start the program might not be run with a shell, so the command `VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox` looks for a program `VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl`, which doesn't exist.

To work around this, use the `env` program to do your variable setting, like so:

```
env VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl firefox
```

Just set the command to the above and it should be fine.